# Creating nested HTML Stucture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What is the best approach of creating HTML Structure in jQuery.
Here are two examples that I have tried, but I am looking for the fastest/best rendering approach.

> jQuery Array Structure Sample

```
var struct = [
  '<div class="daBox-outer">',
    '<div class="daBox-inner">',
      '<div class="daBox-top" />',
      '<div class="daBox-bottom" />',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="daBox-overlay" />',
  '</div>'].join('');

$("body").append(struct);
```

> jQuery Direct Append Sample

```
$("body").append(//->
  '<div class="daBox-outer">' +
    '<div class="daBox-inner">' +
      '<div class="daBox-top" />' +
      '<div class="daBox-bottom" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="daBox-overlay" />' +
  '</div>'
//<-
);
```

I am trying to learn, but can't find proper examples!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to "transform" the HTML (DOM) into the given JSON structure. Is that right?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you currently have?

Comment: I use the structure defined by [JSONML](http://jsonml.org). It's very concise.

Comment: What does [JSON](http://json.org) have to do with this? It looks like straight JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: @ComFreek - Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @FelixKling - Nothing... I just want to try approach with JSON and jQuery combined.

Comment: If you want JSON, you can just take the array literal from your first code example, change single quotes to double quotes and voila, you have JSON. Wikipedia has lots of information and examples about JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON.

Comment: there is no JSON in your question...

Comment: Why not use HTML directly? Why do you want to wrap it like that?

Comment: @Poetro - Can you post the answer ?

Comment: I think first we have to clarify if you really want JSON or not. Do you want to use exactly the code in your first example? Do you consider the array literal as JSON?

Comment: @FelixKling an array literal is a valid JSON and we can consider it a JSON. Although I don't know what good can a JSON do in this situation.

Comment: Well I just want the fastest rendering approach for HTML Structure into jQuery variable. I have seen the best way is using array, constucting structure using .push, .pop and .join but I don't know where I found such a thing to learn from it.

Comment: @Poetro: No. JSON is a clearly defined *textual* data-exchange format (http://json.org/). An array literal is a syntax construct of the JavaScript language (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4). Both are two completely different things and calling an array literal JSON is just wrong and confusing. Using the wrong terminology when asking for help only causes more trouble because your actual intentions are unclear.

Comment: @NenaddvL: Then your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. Please update it accordingly.

Comment: @FelixKling - you're probably right... Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").append(//->
  '<div class="daBox-outer">' +
    '<div class="daBox-inner">' +
      '<div class="daBox-top" />' +
      '<div class="daBox-bottom" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="daBox-overlay" />' +
  '</div>'
//<-
);
```

Also you could use a "JSON" to wrap the HTML string into, but I don't really see any reason to use a JSON here.

```
var jsonData = {
  html: '<div class="daBox-outer">...</div>'
};
$(document.body).append(jsonData.html);
```

Comment: Used long while ago... I don't like this approach for some reason.

Comment: Note that you are using an object literal, not JSON.